# Libgdx CubemapAttribute: How can I use Libgdx's CubemapAttribute for creating reflections?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I read on Internet that Libgdx now supports cubemaps, and I'm treating to figure out how to add one to my game. I searched for an example on StackOverflow but I just found one and it looks obsolete. I don't have too much experience with OpenGL shaders so it would be nice if Libgdx can provide me with a cubemap without having to read a whole big book on OpenGL shaders just for adding a reflection effect to a shield in my game. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [cubemap](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture) is generic, just like a 2d texture. It can be used for whatever you like. You can also have multiple cubemaps for different purposes. Likewise the [`CubemapAttribute`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment#cubemapattribute) can be used to add a cubemap to your environment or material. Just like the [`TextureAttribute`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment#textureattribute) can be used to add a 2d texture.

You can create a cubemap as follows:

```
Cubemap cubemap = new Cubemap(
    Gdx.files.internal("image_px.png"),
    Gdx.files.internal("image_nx.png"),
    Gdx.files.internal("image_py.png"),
    Gdx.files.internal("image_ny.png"),
    Gdx.files.internal("image_pz.png"),
    Gdx.files.internal("image_nz.png"), false);
```

[Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/g3d/environment) you can find some example images which you can use to create a cubemap. Make sure to adjust the name accordingly.

A cubemap holds OpenGL resources and therefor need to be disposed when no longer needed. Don't forget to add this line to your `dispose` method:

```
cubemap.dispose();
```

A typical usage for cubemap is to provide an "environment map" which is used to mimic reflections. You can add such map to your environment as follows:

```
environment.set(new CubemapAttribute(CubemapAttribute.EnvironmentMap, cubemap));
```

If you use the [`DefaultShader`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#default-shader) implementation then it will bind this cubemap to the `u_environmentCubemap` uniform, so you can use it in your shader.

Note that the default shader program (the glsl files) don't support reflections, you will have to use a different shader for that. You can use [this shader](https://gist.github.com/xoppa/9766698) if you like. Note that the material of your model must be reflective ([see this example material](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/g3d/materials/metal01.g3dj#L9)).

```
modelBatch = new ModelBatch(new DefaultShaderProvider(
    Gdx.files.internal("vertex.glsl"),
    Gdx.files.internal("fragment.glsl")));
```

If you want to use the cubemap in your own shader then you can use it basically [like this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/g3d/shaders/reflect.glsl#L64) (just a simple example, i'll not go into the actual shader writing because that's beyond the scope of the question):

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(textureCube(u_environmentCubemap, reflectDir).rgb, 1.0);
```

Comment: Wow! Wonderful answer, thanks Xoppa

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Xoppa. I tested that shaders and, well, I found a bug in the fragment.glsl in the line 215. Now it is: `vec4 specular = vec4(0.0);` and it should be `vec3 specular = vec3(0.0);` I corrected it and it works, and I don't know if I'm doing something bad but if I set the Cubemap attribute, I can't set ambient light, right? If I can, how can I do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the gist and modify it according to your change when I find some time to test it on a few devices. I haven't checked the shader with all possible combinations of lights and materials (which is almost impossible to do), so it might be that some combination has issues. Ambient light is practically just adding a value to gl_FragColor so you could use that as base of your own shader if needed. Implementing that is beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited to its own question, but I just wanted to ask, is there a way to use a `Cubemap` as a skybox instead of just for reflections? Like you did with the space sphere in [this](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/) tutorial of yours.

Comment: Sure, everything is possible, but I don't see why you would ever want to do that. Anyways, that's indeed beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Mostly because it's easier to make textures for a skybox than it is for a sphere, and for the fact that a box uses less polygons.

Comment: You don't need a cubemap to render a box. Anyways, let's not abuse the comments for this.